# scp files and delete files on remote directory

Tags: scripting, scp

I am a unix noob, so please be patient :-)

I have a script that scps a bunch of files to another server.

Suppose they are z1.foo, z2.foo etc. What I want to do is to scp files and delete files older than 5 days in the destination server.

How do I securely delete files from the destination?

Thanks.

Comment: "overwrite the files at the destination"? If you scp files that already exist on the remote dir they'll be overwritten automatically

Comment: its good idea, to delete the files with a shell script locally.meaning that you are SCPing files whenever you like. but there is shell script which runs on daily basis  to remove the files under a certain folder, where you keep the files.command will be something like:`find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;`

Answer (score 28):

To remove files non-interactively:

```
ssh hostname "rm -f z100.foo z200.foo"
```

Comment: what is hostname? is it `servername@ipaddress:path/to/dir/` ?

Comment: hostname is just `user:password@ipaddress` or `user:password@dnsname` or you can omit the password if not needed. I just tried it with `root@somednsname` and it works fine. The `path/to/dir` part I put in the rm command, as an absolute path, to make sure it is correct.

Comment: I don't think `user:password@ipaddress` works tho, only `user@ipaddress` works...

Comment: if the command need SUDO???

Answer (score 12):

You could accomplish both tasks in the same command by using the `--delete` flag to `rsync`.

```
> ls -1 localdir/
a.foo
b.foo

> ssh remote-host "ls -1 remotedir/"
c.foo

> rsync -a --delete localdir/ remote-host:remotedir/

> ssh remote-host "ls -1 remotedir/"
a.foo
b.foo
```

The `--delete` option removes files from the destination directory that don't exist on the source.  There are some choices about when the files are deleted and how to handle excluded files.

```
> man rysnc
...
--delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
--delete-before         receiver deletes before transfer (default)
--delete-during         receiver deletes during xfer, not before
--delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not before
--delete-excluded       also delete excluded files from dest dirs
```

The man page also contains this warning:

> This option can be dangerous if used incorrectly!  It is a very good idea to run first using the `--dry-run option` (`-n`) to see what files would be deleted to make sure important files aren't listed.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to set username and port number you can do the following:

```
ssh root@203.0.113.123 -p22 "rm -rf /home/amzad/test.php"
```